# React: get redux state in router onEnter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have googled this to death and it's very clear that this is a common problem however all of the solutions I found don't seem to fit my case.

I am a react novice and have adopted the following code:

```
const App = {
    path: 'app',
    onEnter: function (nextState, replace) {
        console.log("onEnter", nextState);
        /* somehow listen for redux state
        if (!state.auth.user) {
            replace('/login')
        }
        */
    },
    getChildRoutes(partialNextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            cb(null, [
                require('./routes/dostuff'),
                require('./routes/domorestuff'),
            ])
        })
    },
    getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        require.ensure([], (require) => {
            cb(null, require('./components/AppLayout'))
        })
    }
};

module.exports = App;
```

As per the comment in the onEnter I need to authenticate before entering this route but I am unsure how to do this.

I tried the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.auth.user
    }
};

module.exports = connect(
    mapStateToProps
)(App);
```

but this produces "Uncaught Error: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"path":"app"}"

The following code is used to create bootstrap the app and store:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {applyRouterMiddleware, Router, Route, hashHistory, IndexRedirect, Redirect} from 'react-router';
import {syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware} from 'react-router-redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const middleware = routerMiddleware(hashHistory);
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(middleware)
);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store);

function scrollToTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

const rootRoute = {
    childRoutes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: require('./containers/App'),
        indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/login')},
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/forgotPassword'),
            require('./routes/login'),
            {
                path: '*',
                indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/404')},
            }
        ]
    }]
};

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router
            onUpdate={scrollToTop}
            history={history}
            routes={rootRoute}
        />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app-container')
);
```

I am using the following versions:

```
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
"react-redux": "^5.0.5",
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
"redux": "~3.6.0",
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you create your store?

Comment: What version of react router are you using? Could you post a little bit more code for the context of app? I think I have an idea but i'm not sure if it applies to your case.

Comment: Thank you.  I have edited the question to hopefully contain the info you need.

Comment: Is this in the server? on the front-end? I'd like to know more about that require(/components/app) statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do what you want.  You need to somehow expose the store to your app file and it is currently out of scope.  The basic idea would be to create a function that accepts the store and expose it:

```
function App(store) {
    return {
      path: 'app',
      onEnter: function (nextState, replace) {
          // here you can do stuff with your store, something like store.getState()
          if (!state.auth.user) {
              replace('/login')
          }
          */
      },
      getChildRoutes(partialNextState, cb) {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, [
                  require('./routes/dostuff'),
                  require('./routes/domorestuff'),
              ])
          })
      },
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
          require.ensure([], (require) => {
              cb(null, require('./components/AppLayout'))
          })
      }
    }
};

module.exports = App;
```

and

```
const rootRoute = {
    childRoutes: [{
        path: '/',
        component: require('./containers/App')(store),
        indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/login')},
        childRoutes: [
            require('./routes/forgotPassword'),
            require('./routes/login'),
            {
                path: '*',
                indexRoute: {onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('/404')},
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Great!  Thank you